# Tensorflow Time series forecasting example: how can i scale back the predicted data?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, prediction

I am going through this [introduction to the time series forecasting using RNNs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) and I am adapting the code to a different dataset.

As the data gets normalized using:

```python
uni_train_mean = uni_data[:TRAIN_SPLIT].mean()
uni_train_std = uni_data[:TRAIN_SPLIT].std()
uni_data = (uni_data-uni_train_mean)/uni_train_std
```

I assumed that the predicted value should be scaled back, but I am trying to figure out how to do it with no success. Any help would be much appreciated here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is the process to scale back your prediction

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred*uni_train_std) + uni_train_mean
```

this is simply the inverse operation of scaling